# Not able to send messages to kafka on AWS EC2, from producer written in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-platform

Conflunet Kafka 5.0.0 has been installed on AWS EC2 which has Public IP say 54.XX.XX.XX
Opened port 9092 on the EC2 machine with 0.0.0.0

In /etc/kafka/server.properties I have advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://54.XX.XX.XX:9092  and also listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
In /etc/kafka/producer.properties I have bootstrap.servers=0.0.0.0:9092

Local file iotstatesboto.py has been written as below, it has confluent producer code:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import json

broker = '54.XX.XX.XX'
topic = 'mytopic'

def delivery_report(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {}'.format(msg.topic()))

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': broker})
    message = json.dumps(event)
    print(message)
    p.produce(topic, message.encode('utf-8'), callback=delivery_report)
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

zip package is made locally as below:

```
pip install confluent_kafka has been done in the same directory
zip -r iotstatesboto.zip iotstatesboto.py confluent*
```

This zip file is uploaded to Lambda function.
Then when "Test" function sends a dummy message, following error comes

first:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'iotstatesboto'"
}
```

and one more as:

```
Unable to import module 'iotstatesboto': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'
```

I have set handler name as "iotstatesboto.lambda_handler"

Any clue what could be missing in the steps, to get producer from lambda function to write to kakfa stream on EC2?

Comment: Confluent Kafka relies on compiled C libraries (librdkafka), that won't exist as part of your ZIP file.

Comment: We will try to make the AWS Lambda usage of confluent-kafka-python (with friends) more stream lined, it currently takes a bit of wrangling but is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

When using AWS Lambda you have to provide all the libraries manually, i.e. add them to zip you are using for your lambda function code. You also have to add all the shared object libs if there are any.

AWS Lambda provides you with, in this case, python environment which consists of the Python standard library + Boto3, so there are no other libs there.

Comment: i had done 'pip install confluent_kafka -t ./"  for installing confluent-kafka in the local directory. I am adding the it manually in the zip along with the lambda handler python code.  The combined zip is being uploaded for the AS Lambda function.

Comment: Could you please check if your files are globally readable? I've faced an issue with permissions before. Also, if you are zipping this in Windows environment, this might cause some issues too as Lambdas run on *nix envs.

Comment: I had the same issue while using `pip install confluent_kafka -t ./` turnd out, I was using python3.8 on my local machine (where I was building zip file), while lambda was configured for python3.7. Changing my local version fixed the problem.